# I made this kinda simple code which should read my syntax(which is 'prt(Nice)'), but it throws this: IndexError: string index out of range

Tags: python

Code:

```
f = open('C:/Users/Sasha/Desktop/file.txt','r')
fc = f.readline()
LinesToRead = 2
StartArg = fc.find('(') + 1
EndArg = fc.find(')') - 1
ArgLength = EndArg - (StartArg - 1)
ReadArgChar = ""
ReadFuncChar = ""
Arg = ""
Func = ""
FuncStart = 0
FuncEnd = 3
x = StartArg
y = FuncStart
line = 0

for i in range(LinesToRead):
    # This For loop reads the function's argument:
    for i in range(ArgLength):
        ReadArgChar = fc[x]
        Arg += ReadArgChar
        x += 1
        if x == (EndArg + 1):
            break

    # This For loop reads the function:
    for i in range(FuncEnd):
        ReadFuncChar = fc[y]
        Func += ReadFuncChar
        y += 1
        if y == (FuncEnd + 1):
            break

    # This if-else statement interprets the function syntax:
    if Func == "prt":
        print(Arg)
    elif Func == "brk":
        print("[Program Finished...]")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Sasha\Desktop\PlanetScript.py", line 20, in <module>
    ReadArgChar = fc[x]
IndexError: string index out of range'
```

Comment: Please share some sample from the file?

Comment: You've posted some code, you've posted an error. What is your question? What is not clear about the error you currently get that we can further explain? What steps have you taken to debug your own code? Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: Given `fc[x]` is throwing an index error, check what value `x` has and what value `fc` has.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the position fc[x] with `x = StartArg = fc.find('(') + 1` in `fc = f.readline()` could be out of string. For example in the case the `fc.find('(')` is at the end of a line and adding +1 puts it beyond the `len(fc)`. I'd suggest to include some print() statements of the above mentioned variables.

Answer (score 0):

readline -> readlines

You're reading 1 line at the time and using the index to get the xth (where x is 0 or 1) character in the line. Insteadm you want the xth line. Using readlines, you get the whole file in an array.